# Gradle Error When Adding compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

Hello im new on android and i want to learn 'how to make a simple chat app' from this link : 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397

This is my gradle files :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

//    untuk chat
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
//    untuk chat

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

[image: This is my Error (On Hover)]

The red under line appears at compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' after adding the compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'.

Sorry for my bad English, CMIIW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

You are using mismatching library versions. Please add this `com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1` to your apps gradle. Also I think you should install the *Repository* as said on the first warning. If none of this works, click on the red line and hit *alt+enter* and see what you can do with the options that appears.

Comment: You are using mismatching library versions. Please add this `com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1` to your apps gradle. Also I think you should install the Repository as said on the first warning. If none of this works, click on the red line and hit 'alt+enter' and see what you can do with the options that appears.

Comment: okay, but i dont know how to install the repository.
is it on the sdk tools?

Comment: Just press "Install Repository and sync project" you can find it at the first error message ( look on the photo you uploaded if you cannot find it ). You can find it even on the sdk tools. Does the red line still remaining?

Comment: Hi Moisoni. Could you edit your main answer with the details in the comments section here? It's better to have the *good stuff* to be in the actual answer section. Cheers! :)